# How to resize image before it upload on server with Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am using Laravel Nova v4.0, and am trying to resize the image before uploading it to server. Suppose someone selects an image of 8mb which is very heavy, I need to resize this image to somewhere around 100kb or 200kb and then upload to server.

I know that I can use validation, but I want the user to upload any size and the let the code resize the image. Is it possible?

I have tried this:

```php
Image::make('Image', 'meta->image_path')
    ->required()
    ->prunable()
    ->resize(100, 100, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    })
    ->disk(\App\Models\SomeModel::disk())
    ->path(\App\Models\SomeModel::uploadPath())
    ->maxWidth(150)
    // ->rules("image", "max:200", "min:100")
    ->disableDownload()
    ->preview(function () {
        return $this->logo_url;
    })
    ->thumbnail(function () {
        return $this->logo_url;
    })
    ->displayUsing(function () {
        return $this->logo_url;
    }),
```

But i'm getting this error:

> Method Laravel\Nova\Fields\Image::resize does not exist.

Comment: Laravel nova does not provide image manipulation. Any customization before storage you can do only using the method "store". Please check the [documentation](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/resources/file-fields.html#customizing-file-storage) .   For example, you can install [intervention](https://image.intervention.io/v2/api/resize) package  and use it in "store" method.